# Jquery help me analyze what happened: mouseover/mouseout ok but not hover/unhover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been working on some code where I trigger the code on `hover/unhover`. Then I decided to trigger the same code also on `focus/blur`. Usually with `hover/unhover` only, I go for the usual `hover comma no unhover` format. But this time since I was trying to add `focus/blur`, I had to use bind and use `this.bind` with the second part too, like this:

```
$.fn.gogogo = function (msg) {
    $(this).bind("hover focus", function(){ 
        $("#screen").html(msg).show();
    });
    $(this).bind("unhover blur", function(){ 
        $("#screen").html("").hide();
    });
}
```

The problem was that no matter what I did, `hover/unhover` didn't take. I had to revert back to `mouseover/mouseout` like this. The code is identical except for the words `hover/unhover` vs. `mouseover/mouseout`

```
$.fn.gogogo = function (msg) {
    $(this).bind("mouseover focus", function(){ 
        $("#screen").html(msg).show();
    });
    $(this).bind("mouseout blur", function(){ 
        $("#screen").html("").hide();
    });
}
```

I thought hover/unhover was just the jquery abstraction of mouseover/mouseout. How come the behavior is different here: `hover/unhover` breaks my code, while `mouseover/mouseout` is ok?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no event called `hover`.

The `hover` method is a convenience method that binds event handler to the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.

If you open the jQuery source, you'll see that the `hover` method is defined like this:

```
hover: function(fnOver, fnOut) {
    return this.mouseenter(fnOver).mouseleave(fnOut);
},
```

---

You should bind to the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events instead.

---

**EDIT**: The difference between `mouseenter` and `mouseover` is that `mouseenter` (and `mouseleave`) don't bubble.  This means that you'll get a `mouseover` event if the mouse moves into any element inside the one you bound to (which is probably not what you want), whereas you'll only get a `mouseenter` event if the mouse entered that element itself.  For an example, see the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/mouseover#demo).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I bound to `mouseover/mouseout` and it worked. What's the difference between the `mouseover/mouseout` I have now and `mouseenter/mouseleave`?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "hover" event.  That's just a convenience routine.