# Why is live() and load() not working?

Tags: jquery

I have a page that works perfectly when it's rendered upon page load. (My rows are supposed to highlight when I hover over them.)

When I load the page via a jQuery load event, the page renders perfectly, but the rows do not highlight when hovered over.

I'm pretty sure the problem is that the DOM isn't being updated when load occurs.  Usually, this is solved easily by integrating the live event.

This isn't working though.  Might you know why it's not working?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#ListByFranchisor").live("click", function() {
        $("#ListResultsDiv").load("advisors/recommendationsbyfranchisors.cfm").slideDown();
});

});
</script>



$(".data tr:not(.head)").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('over');
});

$(".data tr").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('over');
});
```

Comment: What is the code for the live() hover effect - as that's the part that's not working presumably?

Comment: Where is the `hover` function?

Comment: Do I just need to add the live event to the mouseover/mouseout events rather than the "$("#ListByFranchisor").live("click"?

Comment: @Evik When putting HTML/code, please ensure you click the code formatting button (Looks like {}) so that it appears correctly. As for the hover function, you say that it should highlight when you hover, but you're not including any code that handles that - only the click event (ahh - you've included the mouse events now)

Comment: The live("click") isn't doing anything re. hover.  Also why not just use CSS?

Comment: The reason I didn't include it was that it is working 100% just fine and doesn't need to be touched, which, I think now, is totally wrong.  Ugh.  I think I will try the solution below.

Comment: @Evik James: hehe let that be a lesson ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `live()` for the event you want to bind on the dynamicly added elements and NOT on the function that adds the elements.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ListByFranchisor").click(function() {
    $("#ListResultsDiv").load("advisors/recommendationsbyfranchisors.cfm").slideDown();
  });

  $(".data tr:not(.head)").live('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).addClass('over');
  });

  $(".data tr").live('mouseout', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('over');
  });
});
```

Also you might want to look into `delegate()` for better performance.

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: This is exactly how my code looks now. It completely solved the problem and I understand why.  Thanks!!!  I will check into delegate().

Comment: @Evik james: Glad to be able to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){  
  $(".data tr:not(.head)").live({
            mouseenter:function()
               {
                 $(this).addClass('over');
               }
    });

    $(".data tr").live({
             mouseleave:function()
               {
                 $(this).removeClass('over');
               }
    });
});
```

EDIT

The difference between mouseenter and mouseover is that mouseenter (and mouseleave) don't bubble. This means that you'll get a mouseover event if the mouse moves into any element inside the one you bound to (which is probably not what you want), whereas you'll only get a mouseenter event if the mouse entered that element itself. For an example, see the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover#demo).

REF: [Jquery help me analyze what happened: mouseover/mouseout ok but not hover/unhover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585643/jquery-help-me-analyze-what-happened-mouseover-mouseout-ok-but-not-hover-unhover)

[**Here**](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html#mouseenter) is another link

Comment: This is what I needed, just a little late.  Is there any difference between mouseover and mouseenter and mouseout and mouseleave?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

> ```
> $(".data tr:not(.head)").live('mouseover',function(){ $(this).addClass('over');}).live('mouseout',function(){$(this).removeClass('over');});
> ```

Comment: Yeah, this looks like what I needed, just a little late, if you can believe it.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use .delegate() on the container and you're set

```
$(".data").delegate('tr:not(.head)', 'mouseover', function() {
   $(this).addClass('over');
}).delegate('tr.over', 'mouseout', function() {
   $(this).removeClass('over');
});
```